# Is there a more robust way to edit the pattern matched, and then replace it?

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

Is there a way to edit a matched pattern and then replace another pattern with the edited pattern?

Input:

```
a11.t
some text here
a06.t
some text here
```

Output:

```
a11.t 11
some text here
a06.t 06
some text here
```

The above example shows the first two digits (matched by first pattern) extracted and placed at the end of the line (second pattern).

In a programming language, I would load the file into a data structure, edit, replace, and write to a new file. But is there a one-line equivalent?

Trial:

```
sed 's/\(a[0-9][0-9].*\)/& \1/I' stack.fa | sed -e 's#a##g2' -e 's#\.\w##g2'
```

Trial output:

```
a11.t 11
some text here
a06.t 06
some text here
```

Obviously the trial works, but is there a more robust way? Further, is there another text processing language this could done in more easily?

Comment: Do we need to consider cases where you have more than one set of digits on the same line? Can you have things like `foo 10 bar 20 baz` and, if yes, what should happen to it? Should it become `foo 10 bar 20 baz 10 20` or just `foo 10 bar 20 baz 10`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`sed` here is the perfect tool for the task. However note that you almost never need to pipe several `sed` invocations together as a `sed` script can be made of several commands.

If you wanted to extract the first sequence of 2 decimal digits and append following a space to end of the line if found, you'd do:

```
sed 's/\([[:digit:]]\{2\}\).*$/& \1/' < your-file
```

If you wanted to do that only if it's found in second position on the line and following a `a`:

```
sed 's/^a\([[:digit:]]\{2\}\).*$/& \1/' < your-file
```

And if you don't want to do it if that sequence of 2 digits is followed by more digits:

```
sed 's/^a\([[:digit:]]\{2\}\)\([^[:digit:]].*\)\{0,1\}$/& \1/' < your-file
```

In terms of *robustness* it all boils down to answering the question: *what should be matched?* and *what should not be?*. That's why it's important to specify your requirements clearly, and also understand what the input may look like (like *can there be digits in the lines where you don't want to find a match?*, *can there be non-ASCII characters in the input?*, *is the input encoded in the locale's charset?* etc.).

Above, depending on the `sed` implementation, the input will be decoded into text based on the locale's charmap (see output of `locale charmap`), or interpreted as if each byte corresponded to a character and bytes 0 to 127 interpreted as per the ASCII charmap (assuming you're not on a EBCDIC based system).

For `sed` implementations in the first category, it may not work properly if the file is not encoded in the right charset. For those in the second category, it could fail if there are characters in the input whose encoding contains the encoding of decimal digits.

Comment: +1 but why include a redirection for the input file ?

Comment: @Cbhihe, why not? There are plenty of good reasons to prefer redirection over passing a filename argument to the command for it to open the corresponding file themselves. You'll find a number Q&As covering that here.

Comment: @Cbhihe one example: try `echo "foo" > file1; chmod oug-r file1; echo "bar" > file2; sed 's/o/O/' < file1 > file2; cat file2; sed 's/o/O/' file1 > file2; cat file2` and note that the approach with input redirection doesn't zap `file2` when `file1` can't be opened.

Comment: @EdMorton: I'd never realized that before. (Does it ever stop,  o_O  ¿@#!? ) Thank you.

Answer (score 13):

Although it has fallen out of fashion, few languages can match perl for text processing. For instance:

1. Assume only one set of numbers, copy to the end of the line:

   ```
    $ perl -pe 's/.*?a(\d+).*/$& $1/' file
    a11.t 11
    some text here
    a06.t 06
    some text here
   ```
2. Multiple sets of numbers, add both to the end

   ```
    $ cat file
    a11.t
    some text here
    a06.t
    some text here
    a11.t a54.g

    $ perl -pe '@nums=(/a(\d+)/g); s/$/ @nums/' file
    a11.t 11
    some text here 
    a06.t 06
    some text here 
    a11.t a54.g 11 54
   ```

Comment: While Perl may be passe, you would be hard-pressed to find a *nix installation that doesn't automatically have it installed. Python might be the only one to compete at that distinction.

Comment: @UncleCarl you're preaching to the choir :)

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way is via the following:

```
$ perl -lne '$,=$"; print $_, /a(\d+)/' file
# or this 
$ perl -lpe 's/a(\d+).*\K/ $1/' file
```

```
$ awk '
    match($1, /^a[[:digit:]]+/) &&
    gsub(/$/, FS substr($1, RSTART+1, RLENGTH-1)) ||
  1' file
```

Note:it is safe to use `substr` within `gsub`'s replacement portion since we already made sure it is pure digital.

Answer (score 0):

command

```
sed 's/\([a-z]\{1,\}\)\([0-9]\{2\}\)\(\..*\)/& \2/g' file
```

output

```
a11.t 11
some text here
a06.t 06
some text here
```

Python

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import re
m=re.compile(r'[0-9]')
k=open('g','r')
for i in k:
    if re.search(m,i):
        print i.strip(),i.split(".")[0][1:]
    else:
        print i.strip()
```

output

```
a11.t 11
some text here
a06.t 06
some text here
```

Answer (score 0):

`perl` or `sed` are the way to go, but just for the sake of completion, a re-write of @PraveeenKumarBS' python snippet's first version, using module `re`'s concept of matched "group":

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import re
pattern = re.compile(r'(\d{2})')
with open('data', 'r') as file:
    for line in file:
        match = re.search(pattern, line)
        if match:
            print(line.rstrip('\n'), match.group(1))
        else:
            print(line.rstrip('\n'))
```

If as OP seems to imply the pattern to look for always includes a first letter, just make the pattern: `pattern = re.compile(r'[a-zA-Z](\d{2})')`.

The corner(?) case of more than one match per line (as remarked by @terdon) is also easily dealt with using a new match expression `match = re.finditer(pattern, line)` and a modified `print` instruction.